# How to open a view with a button clicked as default

Tags: iphone, uibutton

In my app i want to open a view with the content of a particular button (so that button should look clicked and should be not clickable). I have 4 button with pictures and all the four have different content inside them (Table view with different content).When this view gets open i want the first button clicked automatically and the content of that button should get displayed and by clicking any other button the content of that button should get displayed and the previous clicked button should be available to click again.
I am using different pictures for clicked and unclicked button.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

```
- (void)didClickButton:(id)sender {
UIButton *optionButton = (UIButton *)sender;
if(lastSelectedButton.tag!= optionButton.tag) {
optionButton.selected = YES;
//According to your needs enable or disable the button's interaction
}
```

Here `lastSelectedButton` should be an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like a segmented control.  Essentially the segmented control works like buttons on a tape recorder (dating myself, I know.)  When you press Play, it stays down and can't be pressed again until you press Stop or FF or Rew, etc.  (Ok, Stop doesn't really work that way, but the rest of the buttons do)

Unfortunately, I don't believe you can use your own images in a UISegmentedControl, but fortunately there's an open-source version that should work for you:  https://github.com/xhan/PlutoLand/blob/master/PLSegmentView.h

Once you have the control in place you can change the content of your main view depending on the value of the segmented control.  You can handle that in the UIControlEventValueChanged event

Answer (score 0):

Keep a single selector for all the buttons something like

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(templateSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and make use of the tag to carry any index to the selector

```
[btn setTag:integer];
```

and if you want to keep track of previously clicked button then keep a global (id) and assign the current button address to the that id.

And if you want the first button to be clicked on load then call the function melodramatically during initialization of the first button.

```
[self templateSelected:firstButton];
```